# Iron-router route 'loaded' event

Tags: events, meteor, iron-router

I'm a bit new to iron-router but I'm curious if there's an event handler I can define for after a route is loaded.  If I attempt to call Router.current().data() in Meteor.startup, I get 'undefined' for Router.current().  I'd like to know the 'right' way to start doing things once the data is loaded in that route...

Answer (score 2):

The code you're using is fine - `Router.current().data()`.

The issue is that there is a race condition here. There are two things going on here, Meteor.startup may run before or after the router has decided what route its on. If it runs before the route has loaded, `Router.current()` would be `null`.

You might want to consider putting your code in your route's `onAfterAction` instead. This way it will also run on the correct page too. `Router.current().data()` would give back the wrong data on a different route.

Another thing to keep in mind is with Meteor you download the html, js and css first & have it load. Then the data comes after, so when you're looking for data when the page loads you have to wait for it first, otherwise you wont have anything.

Iron Router also has a hook called `onData` which reactively reruns when the corresponding route's `data()` changes. You can use this to ensure you have the data available and have it run after everything has loaded properly.